# Accessing Files from Folder - freezing UI

Tags: c#

I am accessing some files from a network folder and add them to a listview.

This works just fine as long as said network folder is in use. After a while (I can't change that!) the folder goes into sleep mode.

Trying to access those files now freezes my UI for a couple of seconds even though I access them via backgroundworker task.

Is this just something I have to live with, or do you think I maybe need to change something on my task. Can post you some code if this helps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: multithreading and `BeginUpdate/EndUpdate`

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Sleep mode"?  Is this access via a basic network share on a LAN?

Comment: It is a NAS. It has some kind of auto sleep mode enabled. While on Windows I can access the folder in file explorer just fine. After about 30 minutes file explorer freezes as well while trying to access the folder.

Comment: Sounds like your UI is still somehow coupled with the backgroundworker - or maybe you just use `EnumerateFiles`... please provide relevant code, this is pure blind-guessing right now.